# Cookis expiration

Tags: javascript, cookies

That's a script that handles a pop-up on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ 
    document.onload = checkCookie();
    /**/
    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
      {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
    }
    /**/
    function setCookie()
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 300);
    var c_value="newsleter_swieta_no" + ((300==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie="newsletter_swieta" + "=" + c_value;
    }
    function timeMsg()
    {
    var t=setTimeout("newsletterOn()",1500);
    }
    /**/
    function checkCookie()
    {
    var newsletter_swieta=getCookie("newsletter_swieta");
    if (newsletter_swieta!=null && newsletter_swieta!="")
      {      
      }
    else 
      {
      setCookie();
      timeMsg();
      }
    }
    /**/
    function newsletterOn()
    {
        document.getElementById("white2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("black2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("wrap").style.display = "block";
    }  
    function newsletterOff()
    {
        document.getElementById("white2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("black2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("wrap").style.display = "none";
    }// ]]>
</script>
```

I would like to change it in such a way, that the pop-up would appear every time the user re-enters the website. Even if his last visit was 1 minute ago. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `300==null` is always false. And did you open your console to see if the cookie is registered.

Comment: var t=setTimeout("newsletterOn()",1500); should be var t=setTimeout("newsletterOn",1500);

Comment: @argentum47 `setTimeout` can be called like that too. Though it's preferable to pass it a function directly (`setTimeout(newsletterOn,1500)`).

Comment: ow, didn't know that.

Comment: I know code is correct because it's work perfectly. I don't know how to change it in such a way, that the pop-up would appear every time the user re-enters the website.